# method not working

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I have a method where i am trying to receive an arraylist from another class and store it in a new arraylist. The method is supposed to run when i click on the button, but i get nothing. Instead, my GUI froze, the excecution hangs.

```
public class GUI implements ActionListener {

private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dryck & Ingrediens"); // GUI
private JTextField jtf = new JTextField();// GUI
private JTextArea jl1 = new JTextArea();// GUI
private JList jl = new JList();// GUI
private JButton b = new JButton("Sök");
private JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(jl);// GUI
private JLabel lab = new JLabel("Ange dryck");//GUI
private JLabel lab1 = new JLabel("Walid Shams");
private JLabel lab2 = new JLabel("Kushtrim Brahimi");
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> drinkar = null;//Controller
private ServerHandler serverH = new ServerHandler();

public GUI() {


    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(50, 300, 420, 400);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    js.add(jl);
    js.add(jl1);
    jl1.setEditable(false);
    lab.setBounds(90, 20, 130, 20);
    lab1.setBounds(300, 310, 130, 20);
    lab2.setBounds(300, 330, 130,20);
    jtf.setBounds(50, 40, 150, 40);
    b.setBounds(230, 40, 100, 40);
    jl.setBounds(50, 90, 150, 200);
    jl1.setBounds(210, 90, 150, 200);
    Container con = frame.getContentPane();
    con.setBackground(Color.cyan);



    jtf.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

                if (jtf.getText().length() > 0) {
                    serverH.writeMsg(jtf.getText());
                }
                else {
                    String[] empty = new String[]{""};
                    jl.setListData(empty);
                }
        }
    });


    jl.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
             if (jl.getSelectedIndex() != -1) {
                 String item = (String) jl.getSelectedValue();
                 jl1.setText("");
                 for (String ingrediens : drinkar.get(item)) {
                     jl1.append(ingrediens + "\n");
                 }
             }else{
                 jl1.setText("");
             }
        }
    });
    frame.add(jtf);
    frame.add(jl);
    frame.add(jl1);
    frame.add(lab);
    frame.add(lab1);
    frame.add(lab2);
    frame.add(js);
    frame.add(b);
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource().equals(b)){
        getArrayList();
    }

}

// tar emot arrayen, lagrar i ny array och visar i JList
public void getArrayList() {

    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    ArrayList<String> drinks = new ArrayList<String>();

    drinks = serverH.receiveArrayList();
    System.out.println("the contents of the list" + drinks);

    for(int i = 0; i < drinks.size(); i++){
        model.addElement(drinks.get(i));
    }
    jl.setModel(model);

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI g = new GUI();

}
```

}

This is my serverHandler class which is from where im trying to receive the Arraylist. But it seems that its not going through to my GUI.

```
public class ServerHandler  {

private Socket socket;// ServerHandler
private DataInputStream dis;// ServerHandler
private ObjectInputStream ois = null;// ServerHandler
private DataOutputStream dos;// ServerHandler
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> drinkar;

public ServerHandler(){

    socket = new Socket();
    InetSocketAddress ipPort = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 4444);
    try {
        socket.connect(ipPort);
        dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
//        new Thread(this).start();
}


public ArrayList<String> receiveArrayList() {
    String fromServer;
    try {
        while ((fromServer = dis.readUTF()) != null) {
            if (fromServer.equals("read")) {
                getArrayList();
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return getArrayList();

}

public void writeMsg(String jtf){

    if (dos != null) {
        if (jtf.length() > 0) {
            try {
                dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeUTF(jtf);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.print(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> getArrayList(){

ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        drinkar = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>) (ois.readObject());

        Iterator it = drinkar.keySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            String temp = (String) it.next();
            arr.add(temp);
        }
        System.out.println(arr);


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

    return arr;

}

public ArrayList<String> drinks(){

    ArrayList<String>arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    return null;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ServerHandler sv = new ServerHandler();
}
```

}

Comment: What does the receiveArrayList() method look like?

Comment: And where do you register the GUI as an ActionListener?

Comment: Does ArrayList have a toString method that returns anything useful?  I was under the impression that it didn't.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hnfV7u23 ... the method is called receiveArrayList, on line 50

Comment: the method returns the arraylist itself

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);`  Aaaaargh! ***Use Layouts!***

Comment: Hey. This is not egg zactly what I told yesterday... You shouldn't call getArrrayList once again at the return at the end of receiveArrayList, Return getArrayList from within the while loop. Also, don't swallow that exception there, log it at least with printStackTrace.

Comment: Sorry Andrew, ill remember that next time. Zeller, that was the problem actually, now that i changed it, i do receive my drinks. but i have another problem now, and the last one i think. I had values in my hashmap which i cant reach now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never add the action listener to `b`, your JButton. As a result, `if(e.getSource().equals(b))` is always false because the `b` button never initiates the action. Since this if never evaluates true, the method never gets called.

Comment: oh wow, it froze lol. my button froze. there is something creepy about that method

Comment: @DrWooolie But at least it's running, eh? Are you getting any output or logging/debugging statements? If you're running from an IDE like Eclipse it may be useful to start in debug mode and step through the `getArrayList` function.

Comment: i get no output, when i print the arraylist from the receiveArraylist method where i try to get the arraylist from, i do get my values printed,  but this method doesnt even want to run

Comment: @DrWooolie You need to invoke `fireContentsChanged(...);` after `jl.setModel(model)`, I think. See  the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231820/using-the-jlist-setmodel-method-with-a-class-as-an-argument).

Comment: im sorry, but i have no clue how to invoke it. could you please tell me?

Comment: `model.fireContentsChanged(model, 0, model.getSize()-1)`, I assume. It's a method in AbstractListModel.

Answer (score 1):

OK, to sum up. First, calling getArrrayList twice was not a good idea since second time there is nothing in the socket and you just swallowed the drinks... :) Return getArrayList from within the while loop. About your problem in the last comment, that's a design issue. Return the values from the map as well. I think, you shouldn't strip the keyset and return it as a list (which you could have done easier by `new ArrayList(map.keySet())`). Return with the whole map instead and split it in GUI's getArrayList

Comment: Thank you Zeller, that is exactly what i did and now everything works. I am very thankful, you gave it a lot of time to help me. And i appreciate it. Thanks again